# Is there a solution for this word embedding problem with BERT?

Tags: python, tensorflow, pytorch, nlp, google-colaboratory

I have this text dataset that has 2370 rows. They are pretty long texts so I tokenized the data with the max_length=512:

```
tokenized_texts = bert_tokenizer.batch_encode_plus(
    texts,
    max_length=max_length,
    padding=True,              
    truncation=True,          
    return_tensors='pt',      
    add_special_tokens=True )
```

Then I tried to forward the model like this:

```
with torch.no_grad():
    outputs = bert_model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
    word_embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state
```

But when I run it normally, my colab session keeps crashing over and over again.

Then I tried to use the GPU in the colab, but it returned an out-of-memory error:

```
OutOfMemoryError                          Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-37-35b7a1517324> in <cell line: 2>()
      1 # Generate embeddings using the BERT model
      2 with torch.no_grad():
----> 3     outputs = bert_model(input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask)
      4     word_embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state

9 frames

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/torch/nn/functional.py in layer_norm(input, normalized_shape, weight, bias, eps)
   2541             layer_norm, (input, weight, bias), input, normalized_shape, weight=weight, bias=bias, eps=eps
   2542         )
-> 2543     return torch.layer_norm(input, normalized_shape, weight, bias, eps, torch.backends.cudnn.enabled)
   2544 
   2545 

OutOfMemoryError: CUDA out of memory. Tried to allocate 3.47 GiB. GPU 0 has a total capacty of 14.75 GiB of which 3.26 GiB is free. Process 69733 has 11.49 GiB memory in use. Of the allocated memory 11.28 GiB is allocated by PyTorch, and 91.12 MiB is reserved by PyTorch but unallocated. If reserved but unallocated memory is large try setting max_split_size_mb to avoid fragmentation.  See documentation for Memory Management and PYTORCH_CUDA_ALLOC_CONF
```

I tried everything, including making the max_length in the tokenizer 128, using tensorflow instead of torch, etc.

Comment: Can I asked for Bert model you’re currently used ? I’ll help checking what’s wrong with it

Comment: model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("indolem/indobert-base-uncased")
that one

Answer (score 0):

To make an embedding with huggingface model (not only just BERT), we can try some simple and normal approach like this instead, works for all models and often not encounter with memory problem, by let the tokenizer itself handle the text inputs directly (by not even use `batch_encode_plus`):

```py
import torch
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer

# input texts (can be a very long sentences)
texts=['test1', 'test2', ...]

# load the matched model and tokenizer with a given model name
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("indolem/indobert-base-uncased")
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("indolem/indobert-base-uncased")

# tokenize batch of sentences with truncation to 512 that you need to handle long input text
tokenized_texts = tokenizer(texts, 
                            max_length=512, 
                            truncation=True, 
                            padding=True, 
                            return_tensors='pt')
```

Then, pass the batches of text that are encoded to the model (forward pass)

```py
# forward pass
with torch.no_grad():
    input_ids, attention_mask = tokenized_texts['input_ids'], tokenized_texts['attention_mask']

    outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, 
                    attention_mask=attention_mask)

    word_embeddings = outputs.last_hidden_state
```

By following these steps, you will get an embedding output that is:

`[batch_size, num_seq_tokens, embed_size]`

```py
    print(word_embeddings.shape)
    # output: torch.Size([2, 4, 768])
```

However, in case that there still Out of Memory, consider to reduce the batch size in each iterations would be much efficient to handle such problem.